# Capturing HTML comments using Regex but ignoring a certain comment

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I want to capture html comments with the exception of a specific comment i.e,

```
 <!-- end-readmore-item -->
```

At the moment, I can successfully capture all of the HTML comments using the regex below,

```
(?=<!--)([\s\S]*?)-->
```

To ignore the specified comment, I have tried the lookahead and lookbehind assertions but being new at the advanced level of Regex I am probably missing out on something.

So far, I have been able to devise the following regex using lookarounds,

```
^((?!<!-- end-readmore-item -->).)*$
```

I expect it to ignore the `end-readmore-item` comment and only capture other comments such as,

```
<!-- Testing-->
```

However, it does the job but also captures the regular HTML tags which I want to be ignored as well.

I have been using the following html code as a test case,

```
<div class="collapsible-item-body" data-defaulttext="Further text">Further 
text</div>
<!-- end-readmore-item --></div>
</div>
&nbsp;<!-- -->
it only should match with <!-- --> but it's selecting everything except <!-- 
end-readmore-item -->
the usage of this is gonna be to remove all the HTML comments except <!-- 
end-readmore-item -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```regex
<!--(?!\s*?end-readmore-item\s*-->)[\s\S]*?-->
```

**[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/rXAQgg/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

```
<!--                    # Matches `<!--` literally.
(?!                     # Start of a negative Lookahead (not followed by).
    \s*                 # Matches zero or more whitespace characters.
    end-readmore-item   # Matches literal string.
    \s*                 # Matches zero or more whitespace characters.
    -->                 # Matches `-->` literally.
)                       # End of the negative Lookahead.
[\s\S]*?                # Matches any character zero or more time (lazy match), 
                        # including whitespace and non-whitespace characters.
-->                     # Matches `-->` literally.
```

Which basically means:

> Match `<!--` that is *not* followed by [a whitespace<sup>*</sup> + `end-readmore-item` + another whitespace<sup>*</sup> + `-->`] and which *is* followed by any amount of characters then immediately followed by `-->`.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>An *optional* whitespace repeated zero or more times.</sub>

Comment: This works for me! Can you please explain the expression to me as well?

Answer (score 1):

You are very close with your negative lookahead assertion, you just need to modify it as follows:

```
<!--((?!end-readmore-item).)*?-->
```

Where `*?` matched non-greedily.

This will match all comments except those that contain the string `end-readmore-item` inside the comment body.

Comment: Nice one! The only critique I have is that this checks for the Lookahead _for each character_ of the comment, which is inefficient, especially if you'll be checking against long comments.